# Efficient repeated use of TensorFlow in Java based on SavedModelBundle

Tags: java, tensorflow

I have been given a trained TensorFlow model as a SavedModelBundle and a sketch of how to use it. The code is below.

The problem is that I must not only use it, but repeat this over and over again with different data. These are not all known at the same time. The code below was repeats the entire process from retrieving the saved model to fetch() every time it is called. So it seems more appropriate for a small number of uses.

There are several classes that collaborate in the example, including Model, Session, Runner. I would like to factor out any one-time operation or potentially persistent object and put it in an `init()` function. What I'd like to know are:

1. What is the appropriate objects to relegate to init() and to store? Is it typical to load and configure a runner, store that, and just doing feeds, runs and fetches?
2. Are there Tensor resources I need to close? The documentation has warnings about freeing resources. Will everything be OK when `result` goes out of scope or do I need to call `close()`?

Code:

```
SavedModelBundle model = SavedModelBundle.load(fname); 
Session s = model.session();

Runner runner = s.runner();
int nFeatures = tensorNames.length;
for (int i = 0; i < nFeatures; i++) {
    float[][] featureData = new float[][] { { rawdata[0][i] } };
    Tensor<Float> input = Tensor.create(featureData, Float.class);
    runner.feed(tensorNames[i], input);
}

int nFeatures_int = tensorNames_int.length;
for (int i = 0; i < nFeatures_int; i++) {
    long[][] featureData_int = new long[][] { { rawdata_int[0][i] } };
    Tensor<Long> input_int = Tensor.create(featureData_int, Long.class);
    runner.feed(tensorNames_int[i], input_int);
}

Tensor result = runner.fetch("StatefulPartitionedCall_2:0").run().get(0);
float[][] out = new float[1][1];
result.copyTo(out);
model.close();
return out[0][0];
```